# How can I make dataclass property change every time I call this dataclass?

Tags: python

I have a trouble getting the different value from dataclass that contains another dataclass everytime its called. I'm using this dataclass later in a code to make different numbers for the same variable.

My code:

```
@dataclass
class ClassExample:
    first: int = field(default_factory=lambda: random.choice([1, 2, 3]))
    second: int = field(default_factory=lambda: random.randint(1, 6))


@dataclass
class exp:
    sum_s = ClassExample()


# it'll be the same output for each iteration
for _ in range(3):
    print("first:", exp().sum_s.first) # Output: first: 2, first: 2, first: 2
    print("second:", exp().sum_s.second) # Output: second: 1, second: 1, second: 1
```

What I want:

```
first: 2 
second: 1
first: 3 
second: 4
first: 1
second:5
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you mean `ClassExample().first`? You're not instantiating the class, so of course it does not change the value.

Comment: Please show the error that you get from your current code.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I've spent on this error lots of time, so didn't write it properly
I edited initial message

Comment: The bottom line is you don't really want a dataclass.  Just build a normal class with a normal `__init__` that sets your values appropriately.  There's nothing magic about dataclass that you should try to force it to mold to your concept.

Comment: @python_user well, this is the output
first: <function ClassExample.<lambda> at 0x000001A9E38AF430>
second: <function ClassExample.<lambda> at 0x000001A9E38AF4C0>

Comment: Updated my answer to account for your modification. You may want to rewrite your question more or less from scratch at this point, since the "Update:" makes it into a barely legible mess.

Comment: I see random output when I run the first code block. The *second* doesn't produce random output, of course, because you've only got one instance of `ClassExample`.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an attribute in a dataclass as `field`, its metadata is placed in `ClassExample.__dataclass_fields__`. The class object `ClassExample` does not even have an attribute `first`, only instances do. You see this when you get

```
AttributeError: type object 'ClassExample' has no attribute 'first'
```

You need to instantiate the class to get the initializer to run, e.g.:

```
ClassExample().first
```

Your second class, `exp`, shares the same instance of `ClassExample`. If you want it to generate a new one for each instance, you need to do the same thing you did for `ClassExample`:

```
@dataclass
class exp:
    sum_s = field(default_factory=ClassExample)
```